# JS: Load page content from web (if possible), fallback to local copy

Tags: javascript

I have an application I develop. It should show some stuff like help and legit stuff in a WebBrowser control. This works so far. I can use either a local .mht file or a url.

But I want to use both. So the content will be used online (if possible) or offline if the system has no internet connection.

Now I'm thinking about a pure JS solution, so the script tries to get the page online and displays it, or if it fails uses the local stored copy of it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you appear to be describing sounds like something recently being called [Progressive Web Apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive). Building them is no small task, depending on the complexity of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Any sort of AJAX request you make in any library will let you give an error handler. If an error happens, that's when you load the local copy.